# How to define the style of objects in a collection for one record via SLD

Tags: geoserver, sld

How to define the style of objects in a collection for one record via SLD. For example, lines are separate, polygons are separate.

For instance

```
<Rule>
   <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
      <ogc:Function name="geometryType">
         <ogc:PropertyName>geom</ogc:PropertyName>
      </ogc:Function>
      <ogc:Literal>GeometryCollection</ogc:Literal>
   </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
   <PolygonSymbolizer> -- ONLY POLIGON
     ...
   </PolygonSymbolizer>
   <LineSymbolizer>    -- ONLY LINES
     ...
   </LineSymbolizer>
</Rule>
```

So far, it turns out that the first style is used for all sub-objects of the recording, and the lines are displayed as polygons.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoHBZ.png

Answer (score 0):

A `Rule` will apply all of its `Symbolizer`s to all features that match its filter, so this SLD is behaving exactly as expected.

You need to have multiple rules with different filters:

```
<Rule>
   <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
      <ogc:Function name="geometryType">
         <ogc:PropertyName>geom</ogc:PropertyName>
      </ogc:Function>
      <ogc:Literal>Polygon</ogc:Literal>
   </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
   <PolygonSymbolizer> -- ONLY POLIGON
     ...
   </PolygonSymbolizer>
 </Rule>
 <Rule>
   <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
      <ogc:Function name="geometryType">
         <ogc:PropertyName>geom</ogc:PropertyName>
      </ogc:Function>
      <ogc:Literal>LineString</ogc:Literal>
   </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
   <LineSymbolizer>    -- ONLY LINES
     ...
   </LineSymbolizer>
</Rule>
```

There are more details in the [GeoServer manual](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/tipstricks/mixed-geometries.html), however, none of these techniques will work with a `GeometryCollection` so you will probably need to rework your data flow to avoid ending up with these.

Comment: With regard to individual types, everything is very clear. The conversation is about collections. Apparently you need to study the source code.

Comment: I think I wrote the source code :-) The question is more why are you working with collections?

Comment: A large number of objects have this structure. These are various designs that are grouped together. There is, of course, an option to divide the object into parts, but why not implement the function of a separate coloring of objects? In addition, a filter on the collection already exists.